# Increasing Stack Space

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

When I run the following code:

```
(defun countdown (n)
  (if (>= n 0)
    (cons n (countdown (- n 1)))))

(countdown 100000)
```

I get the following message :

```
INFO: Control stack guard page unprotected
Control stack guard page temporarily disabled: proceed with caution

debugger invoked on a SB-KERNEL::CONTROL-STACK-EXHAUSTED in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002B03653}>:
  Control stack exhausted (no more space for function call frames).
This is probably due to heavily nested or infinitely recursive function
calls, or a tail call that SBCL cannot or has not optimized away.

PROCEED WITH CAUTION.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-KERNEL::CONTROL-STACK-EXHAUSTED-ERROR)
```

**How do I increase the stack space?** I do not want to change the code above; I supplied it purely to illustrate stack exhaustion.

Comment: One might question the design of a program whose stack runs 100K deep.

Comment: @PaulNathan One might indeed. It was for benchmarking purposes, not for a real program. Unfortunately there is not enough space in this little margin to outline it all....

Comment: @PaulNathan : If you are interested it is related to the bubblesort discussion here : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/qilang/cUE5fj7XfjE/ueo3MkB7h30J

Comment: seems reasonable. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `sbcl` with the `--help` option on the command line gives some useful common options, including an option for how to increase the stack space.  You want to to use the `--control-stack-size` argument.

```
$ sbcl --help
Usage: sbcl [runtime-options] [toplevel-options] [user-options]
Common runtime options:
  --help                     Print this message and exit.
  --version                  Print version information and exit.
  --core <filename>          Use the specified core file instead of the default.
  --dynamic-space-size <MiB> Size of reserved dynamic space in megabytes.
  --control-stack-size <MiB> Size of reserved control stack in megabytes.
...
```

By specifying a bigger value there, we can run your code:

```lisp
$ sbcl --control-stack-size 100000
* (defun countdown (n)
  (if (>= n 0)
    (cons n (countdown (- n 1)))))
;=> (100000 … 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly in time for the question at hand, but for anyone also wondering about the `--control-stack-size`:

From the [SBCL manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/) section "3.3.1 Runtime Options" the **default value** for the `--control-stack-size` is **2 megabytes**.

So for a list containing 100k 64bit-integers **7 megabyte** `sbcl --control-stack-size 7` should be sufficient!

As a reference:

```
CL-USER> (type-of 42)
(INTEGER 0 4611686018427387903)
CL-USER> (/ (* 64 100e3) (expt 2 20))
6.1035156
```